# References for the representation theory of $SU(2, 1)$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-actions

I couldn't find any reference with the representation theory of this specific case. I found some general stuff but never explicit computations or realizations.

The only thing I found on $SU(2, 1)$ is a little bit about its structure theory on Helgason's book (Differential geometry, Lie Groups and Symmetric Spaces).

And so I ask you, do any of you know if there is something like this in the literature (I phrase this question as a reference request because I think it would be near impossible to give an explicit answer in here)? Actually, at this point, anything on this group would be great, but I do need to know whatever is known about its representation theory.

Bonus question: 
1) Refenreces on the relation of the rep. theory of $SU(2, 1)$ and $SL(3)$ 
2) The relation to the rep. theory of it's Lie algebra.
3) References on actions of $SU(2, 1)$.

Comment: I this helpful: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pcma/1416336464 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the meaning of "representation" here. In case you mean "unitary representations" by it, a possible reference is [The Structure and Unitary Representations of $SU(2,1)$](http://digitalcommons.bowdoin.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1024&context=honorsprojects), where also the finite-dimensional representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ are classified, and all of your bonus question are answered. A special reference here is $[10]$, a complete PhD-thesis on this topic for $SU(2,1)$ and $S(U(1)\times U(1,1))$. There are many other references as well.

Comment: You, sir, are an angel.